# Trouble starting a MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki

I'm thinking about developing a MediaWiki site. I want to start at localhost. I've never done any web-dev in my life. So I've installed mediawiki thru a synaptic (I'm on Kubuntu 11.10). If I understand it right I has to open `index.php` in localhost. How can I do it? I tried

```
http://localhost/usr/share/mediawiki/index.php
```

but it says "Not found".

P.S. 
When I open localhost - it says "It works!" and nothing else. I thought it should give me an index of home folder or something like that.

Comment: You don't really expect to be able to access your whole file system via http, do you?

Answer (score 2):

Your media wiki URL starts from the path specified in your web server configuration, not your file path. In this case, the info is found in mediawiki.conf under /etc/apache2/conf.d directory.

On my own ubuntu server, it looks like I would have to uncomment out this alias in the file:

```
Alias /mediawiki /var/lib/mediawiki
```

Which allows me to access the URL from here:

```
elinks http://localhost/mediawiki
```

That is probably what you have to do to get it running. Note that it will probably ask you to set it up from that page, so you'll need to review the MediaWiki documentation on how to get that setup from that point on.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I'm stupid, I found the [page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MediaWiki) which explains how this should be done. I wonder we mediawiki docs have skipped these details.